# PHP Exception memory leak

Tags: php, memory-leaks, exception

In my console application, I replaced displaying all PHP built-in error types with throwing `ErrorException`:

```
set_error_handler(function ($severity, $message, $file, $line) {
    if (!(error_reporting() & $severity)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }

    throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $file, $line);
});
```

It works great, but there's one problem. Consider the following snippet:

```
for ($id = 1;; $id += 1) {
    try {
        $html = file_get_contents('https://stackoverflow.com/boo/' . $id);
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        // Failed
    }
}
```

Every `ErrorException` thrown keeps the stack history. In real-life example, some IDs are missing and that causes, so after thousands of iterations, eventually the memory leak occurs.

What can be done to fix this problem? Is throwing and catching exceptions is a loop wrong? Or maybe I could disable the stacking behavior somehow?

Comment: It does create an infinite loop, but it's totally fine for me. I stop it manually when I need to. I need the contents of the file, not just check if it exists, because I use the HTML to parse it.

Comment: Then I will slow it down twice.

Comment: The slowest part of this script is fetching the URL. Checking if it exists and then getting the contents is 2 times per one URL. That's why I would slow it down twice.

Comment: Ah, I missed the fact that you were fetching a URL and not a local file path. Then forget about my previous comments. :-)

Comment: I could think of a workaround without exceptions, but I'm also just curious how to overcome this stacking or to know some good approach in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can unset the Exception object once you've used it on each iteration:

```
function getLevels($start_idx,$levels = 9){
   try {
            return $this->getBinaryTree($levels);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            switch($e->getMessage()){
            case "Almost out of memory":
               $max_tree_depth = (int)($levels/2);
               if($max_tree_depth >= 2){
                    unset($e); // <------------------------ RIGHT HERE!
                    return $this->getLevels($start_idx,$max_tree_depth);
               }else{
                    throw new Exception("Out of memory even after getting tree with 2 levels");
               }
               break;
            default:
               throw $e;
         }
     }
}
```

I found the solution on the link below:

https://stuporglue.org/php-memory-leak-when-throwing-catching-and-recursing/